# ¿no me muetra el alert de las siguiente variables solo muestra el primer dato seleccionado?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<?php 

$user="localhost";
$username="root";
$pass="";
$db="surti_office";

$conexion=mysqli_connect($user,$username,$pass,$db)or die  ("ERROR DE CONEXION");
?>

<?php 
$consultar="SELECT * FROM producto where total_oferta_iva >1 ORDER by idproducto desc limit 20";
$resultado=$conexion->query($consultar);
while ($resultados=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){
?>
<form action="#" id="formulario">

<input type="text" id="input" name="<?php echo $resultados['idproducto']?>" value="<?php echo $resultados['idproducto']?>">
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
<?php }?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#formulario").submit(function(){
        var cadena="";
        cadena = $(this).serialize();
     alert(cadena);
     return false;
     });
     });
</script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te recomiendo que dejes la edición activa para que tu pregunta se pueda leer correctamente, saludos !

Comment: gracias Camilo Vasquez por la ayuda pero necesito tomar el valor de cada unos y mostrar en un alert de la forma en que me dijiste to hace de manera general

Comment: Leonardo, este comentario debía ser en mi respuesta y no en tu pregunta, para que lo tengas en cuenta, teniendo esa info que me acabas de dar te editaré la respuesta con la solución en un par de minutos.

Comment: Ya te he editado la respuesta !

Comment: @Camilo Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Si la respuesta ayudó a tu solución te invito a que la marques como aceptada para que otros desarrolladores sepan que es una solución correcta, ya hiciste el [tour] ? si no lo haz hecho te invito a que lo hagas para que entiendas el funcionamiento básico del sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Si lo que quieres es generar múltiples formularios entonces debes hacer lo siguiente:**

Tienes un error en tu estructura `html` y es que a todos los formulario que se generan les estás asignando el mismo id **nunca se debe de repetir el id de un elemento dentro de tu página** para eso entonces vamos a usar clases de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php 
$consultar="SELECT * FROM producto where total_oferta_iva >1 ORDER by idproducto desc limit 20";
$resultado=$conexion->query($consultar);
while ($resultados=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){
?>
<form action="#" class="formulario">

<input type="text" id="input" name="<?php echo $resultados['idproducto']?>" value="<?php echo $resultados['idproducto']?>">
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
<?php }?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".formulario").submit(function(){
        var cadena="";
        cadena = $(this).serialize();
     alert(cadena);
     return false;
     });
     });
</script>
```

Lo que pasaba en tu caso era que como todos tenían el mismo `id` el sistema solo interactuaba con el primero que encontrara ignorando el resto.